# Ruby and Watir - testing for page load

Tags: ruby, watir

I wrote this script a couple months ago and it has been working great.  However, had an issue last night that the page never loads and just spins forever.  My script was just timing out.  I need to add code to test if the page fully loads within 30 second and if not to exit with a status of 2 and a proper message.  Here is the code I have:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------#
# Watir Login to XXXX SSO Site
#  Written 2017-09-17 for ITC by Jim Clark
#-------------------------------------------------------------#
# the Watir controller
require "watir"
# set a variable
#test_site = "https://oracle.pomeroy.com"
test_site = "http://xxx.xxx"
# open a browser
browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
#puts "Beginning of test: XXXX SSO Login."
#puts " Step 1: go to the test site: " + test_site
browser.goto test_site
# Test if page fully loaded after 30 seconds, if not, exit with proper status and message


# validate login site loads
if browser.text.include? "Username"
  #puts " Step 2: enter username and password text fields."
  browser.text_field(:name, "username").set "xxxx"
  browser.text_field(:name, "password").set "xxxx"
  #puts " Step 3: click login"
  browser.button(:text, "Login").click
  if browser.text.include? "Logged In As XXXX"
    puts "OK: Test Passed.  Login worked!"
    status = 0
  else
    puts "CRITICAL: Open a SEV1 - Test login failed!"
    status = 2
  end
else
  puts "CRITICAL: Open a SEV1 - Could not find login page!"
  status = 2
end
browser.close
exit status
```

I have just spent the last 3 hours searching and reading and tried about 20 different things and nothing I did seemed to work.

Comment: When you say the "script was just timing out" do you mean that an exception occurred when calling `browser.goto`? If so, couldn't you rescue the exception and exit with that specified status?

Comment: The `browser.goto` line times out after 60 seconds and the script just exits with an exception.  I did this to get around it:
`begin
  Timeout::timeout(28) do
    browser.goto test_site
  end
rescue => e
  puts "CRITICAL: Open a SEV1 - Page never loads!"
  exit 2
end
`
Not sure if that was the best method and more than open to feedback

Comment: In ruby it seems there is always more than one way to do things and endless potential discussions over which is the 'best way'.  I'd say if this is working for you, then go ahead and use it.   It's pretty much what I would do if the basic timeout error was not enough to inform me of what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So while the wait methods have a default timeout, settable thusly: `Watir.default_timeout = 30` it appears there is no such setting in Watir itself for the the goto method.  However since this is just calling the webdriver navigate.to method, and there IS a timeout settable in webdriver for that, then you can set that using watir's .driver method prior to trying to goto the page.  You should be able set that as follows

```
b.driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 30
b.goto
```

In your case since it's the initial load that is failing this ought to work for you, and if you don't like the default error message, you could rescue and provide your own.

In most cases I've seen however, the delays are often with REST services that are slow or overloaded, so just setting that prior to your goto will most often not be sufficient if the delays are with subsequent AJAX calls.  What is checked when you use goto is the browser status, which will be 'ready' once the initial page content has been loaded, and often that happens pretty quickly as these days that content is often all static, cached and rapidly served by the webserver.  Basically that is the time for loading a web 1.0 web-page.

Typically modern 'web 2.0' pages have a LOT of scripts and AJAX/REST style interactions that are usually necessary for all the page content to appear. It's not uncommon for the browser to report 'ready' when the page is mostly blank as the remaining contents are pulled in via REST or GRAPHQL requests. There is not unfortunately a standard way to tell if the browser is busy making further requests due to scripts.

The most standard thing to do is wait a given amount of time for a specific condition to be true, usually something to appear on the page that is one of the last things loaded/rendered.  The wait methods take timeout parameterss, so you could do something along these lines

```
b.goto 'www.mysite.com'
Watir::Wait.until(timeout=30) { browser.text_field(name: 'username').exists? }
```

The Watir::Wait.until method (rubydocs [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Wait)) also accepts a custom message if you want to provide one to make it easier to know what timed out when it fails.

Comment: There is no way `Watir.default_timeout` is related to `b.goto`, `b.goto` time setting doesn't depends upon Watir.default_timeout. We can set the timings for b.goto, but there is an another way to do it.

Comment: b.goto will return time if you use watir-classic not when you use recent watir which uses selenium at the back, it simply returns the url which is loaded now.

Comment: I had thought that the default timeout related to more than just the wait methods, but it appears I am wrong..  revising answer accordingly

Comment: I started using Watir around 10 years ago, before watir-webdriver..  but had not used the return of .goto for a LONG time, so did not realize that was unique to the old watir we now call watir-classic.  I've updated the answer to remove references to that..   Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Okay, All right! Actually `driver.manage.timeouts.page_load` has to take care of every page loading after every click, but it's not doing it's Job It's working only for goto method. This is the problem in the Ruby selenium Binding, but not in Java Binding. The reason for this problem is, the variable which is used for read timeout is not receiving the value from `.page_load=30` instead it's hard-coded for 60 seconds ! I believe this is a bug in selenium ruby binding.

Comment: I would file a bug against that in the appropriate webdriver project then.

Comment: Okay! That's great!